# Sitemap XML File does not contain any product, category or content pages URLs

Tags: sitemap, intershop

I want to create a Sitemap XML File and use the "Product Data Feeds" Option in Intershop 7.7. I choose the "Sitemap XML (HTTPS)" Type and the default entries on this page (Products and Categories are checked). In the generated Sitemap XML File are no URL's listed. Any ideas how to do this and which right settings I have to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICM 7.7 does not generate sitemap files which are directly accessible from the administrative backoffice. It generates [sitemap index files](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index). These contain pointers to the actual XML sitemaps where are the URLs. This is just as defined in the sitemap standard. Product data, categories and content occupy different sitemap files.

Here is an example sitemap index file that points to an actual product XML sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
        <loc>https://localhost/WFS/inTRONICS/en_US/-/USD/sitemap-product-sitemap-0</loc>
        <lastmod>2016-10-19T21:36:21+03:00</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

The product URL data is located within the referred file, example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
 <url>
    <loc>https://localhost/WFS/inTRONICS/en_US/-/USD/Computers/206/902/A-DATA-microReader-Ver.3-16GB-microSDHC-Class-10-zid7415685</loc>
    <lastmod>2016-10-14T09:35:12+03:00</lastmod>
 </url>
 ....
</urlset>
```

But not all products are listed in the map by default. Some conditions should be fulfilled otherwise a product may be filtered. To generate a non-empty map:

1. Make sure that URL rewriting is enabled for the channel (you may enable/disable URL rewriting from the Oprations backoffice).
2. Make sure that you have online products in the channel (offline products are skipped).
3. Make sure that some of the online products have valid prices for the currency chosen in the site map configuration (products without prices in the specified currency are filtered).
4. Create and run the site map feed with products.

Rules also exist for categories. E.g. empty categories are excluded.